# Evermore or ever more?

Tags: grammar, programming

Which form is correct in this:

> Files stored on computers become increasingly important as businesses
>   and governments store **evermore** files of evermore importance on
>   automated systems.evermore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines [evermore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evermore) as follows:

> forever, always

It's a (slightly archaic?) expression used in sentences like *I will love you evermore*. It's cousin *nevermore* is of course famous thanks to Edgar Allan Poe's *The Raven* (it croaked *nevermore*) but actually both *evermore* and *nevermore* appear in [the poem](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/48860):

> Eagerly I wished the morrow;—vainly I had sought to borrow
>       From my books surcease of sorrow—sorrow for the lost Lenore—
>   For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore—
>               Nameless here for evermore.
>   ...
>   Then this ebony bird beguiling my sad fancy into smiling,
>   By the grave and stern decorum of the countenance it wore,
>   “Though thy crest be shorn and shaven, thou,” I said, “art sure no craven,
>   Ghastly grim and ancient Raven wandering from the Nightly shore—
>   Tell me what thy lordly name is on the Night’s Plutonian shore!”
>               Quoth the Raven “Nevermore.”

The construction *ever* + *comparative* has a completely different meaning:

> ever bigger: always getting bigger
>   ever higher: always getting higher
>   ever more expensive: always getting more expensive

In the example sentence, the intended meaning seems to be that there are always getting more files which are always getting more important, so there should be a space in between *ever* en *more*.

(Where I use *always*, read *all the time*, *continuously*, *increasingly*, or whatever fits best in context.)